# New site appearing in folder structure after first hit on homepage?

Tags: installation

This one has me scratching my head.  I'm new to Drupal and am trying to restore a backup of a Drupal 7 site to a 3rd party hosting provider (hostgator as it happens.)

I purchased a business account and domain name to experiment with, and via their interface installed Drupal 7 in the `public_html/myaccount` subfolder.

I then restored the backup to that same folder.  Beneath `myaccount` is the typical drupal file structure-- `includes`, `scripts`, `sites` etc.

Beneath the `sites` folder were subfolders `all` and `default`, exactly as restored from the backup and a typical Drupal structure.  But that has changed.

When I browse to `www.myhostedsite.com/myaccount` I get an unstyled version of my site along with messages on the page that say things like:
`Undefined index: highlighted in include() (line 126 of /home4/xyz/public_html/myaccount/modules/system/page.tpl.php).`

...and to my surprise, under the `sites` folder there's now a new folder with the name of the old site, with js and css subfolders beneath it.

How did *that* appear, and would anyone know what I may be doing wrong?  I've noodled with .htaccess and settings.php values but am not sure I know what to look for in either location (though I did set the database connection correctly in settings.php, I'm pretty sure.)

Comment: Instead of `public_html/myaccount`, try putting the site in `public_html` only.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I did that, and unfortunately I have the exact same problem, even though my site is now directly under `public_html`

Answer (score 1):

It would be good if you ask HostGator support guys to assist you through your problem. Got to [Support](https://support.hostgator.com/) and create a support ticket.

Comment: They're the next step, sure, but was wondering if anyone had seen this type of problem after restoring an existing site?